# Command in multiple shell windows for multiiple telnet connection

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, telnet, wsh

i've searched a lot without any results, and so i'm ansking to you!
I want to open multiple windows shell, and then load different telnet connection to send the same commad to different computers. I need that is done at the same time. So, i wrongly try do create different "WScript.Shell" object and use send key on them. Without any result. How can I do that?

```
Option Explicit
Dim tll1, tll2, tll3
set tll1=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set tll2=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set tll3=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

tll1.run "cmd.exe"
tll2.run "cmd.exe"
tll3.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000

tll1.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.114.254"
tll1.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
tll2.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.114.254"
tll2.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
tll3.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.114.254"
tll3.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
...
```

The result it's the wole commands typed in the last shell window. Thanks!

Comment: The IP address is the same because i'm using a single machine fot initial test.

Comment: You only need to create ONE "Wscript.Shell". Use AppActivate. Look it up in help for WScript.Shell.

Comment: PS You'll need to use Telnet direct (rather than starting cmd then telnet) and have a different IP address for each window so you have a different window title for each window.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Noodles. I've done it! the only things to remind is to put a sleep between the AppActivate and the command. Without does not work for me, here the final code

```
Option Explicit

Dim wshShell
set wshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.run "telnet.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "o 192.168.114.251"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "admin"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys ""
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "CMD_PC1"

wshShell.run "telnet.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "o 192.168.114.252"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "admin"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys ""
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "CMD_PC2"

wshShell.run "telnet.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "o 192.168.114.254"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "userPC3"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "PWD_PC3"
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.SendKeys "CMD_PC3"
WScript.Sleep 1000

wshShell.AppActivate "Telnet 192.168.114.251"
WScript.Sleep 3
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
wshShell.AppActivate "Telnet 192.168.114.252"
WScript.Sleep 3
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
wshShell.AppActivate "Telnet 192.168.114.254"
WScript.Sleep 3
wshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
Wscript.Quit
```